# Cannot fetch records from public database using cloudkit

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

This is a method I call to fetch public records:

```
private func fetchPublicRecordZonesChanges(completion: ErrorHandler?) {
    let zone = CKRecordZone.default()
    let options = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOptions()
    options.previousServerChangeToken = nil

    var records = [CKRecord]()
    var recordIDsToDelete = [CKRecordID]()
    let operation = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation(recordZoneIDs: [zone.zoneID], optionsByRecordZoneID: [zone.zoneID: options])
    operation.database = CloudAssistant.shared.publicDatabase
    operation.recordChangedBlock = { record in
        records.append(record)
    }

    operation.recordWithIDWasDeletedBlock = { recordID, string in
        recordIDsToDelete.append(recordID)
    }

    operation.recordZoneChangeTokensUpdatedBlock = { _, token, _ in
        if let token = token {
            Token.temporaryPublicZoneServerChangeToken = token
        }
    }

    operation.recordZoneFetchCompletionBlock = { [weak self] _, token, _, _, error in
        if let error = error, error.isTokenExpiredError {
            UserDefaults.remove(forKey: PublicZoneServerChangeTokenKey)
            self?.fetchPublicRecordZonesChanges(completion: completion)
            return
        }
        if let token = token {
            Token.temporaryPublicZoneServerChangeToken = token
        }
    }

    operation.fetchRecordZoneChangesCompletionBlock = { [weak self] error in
        self?.save(records: records, recordIDsToDelete: recordIDsToDelete) { error in
            completion?(error)
        }
    }
    operationQueue.addOperation(operation)
}
```

But nothing is fetched although that method is called, additionally not even once `recordChangedBlock` closure is called. Why?

I am pretty sure I have a records there:

[image]

and environment is also very fine, because private **development** records are fetched correctly (using of course different method). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation can only be used with private or shared databases, not the public database.

Comment: Wow, thank you;) I didnt know that. What can I use to fetch all changes from public database?

Comment: are you serious only Private DB or shred DB?!? i just wasted days trying to find a way to fetch changes for public DB

Answer (score 2):

To be notified of changes to your Public database, create a `CKQuerySubscription` for the record type(s) you care about. Here's an example:

```
let subscription = CKQuerySubscription(
  recordType: "Question", 
  predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), 
  subscriptionID: "subscriptionQuestion", 
  options: [
    .firesOnRecordCreation, 
    .firesOnRecordUpdate, 
    .firesOnRecordDeletion
  ])

let info = CKNotificationInfo()
info.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
subscription.notificationInfo = info

let operation = CKModifySubscriptionsOperation(subscriptionsToSave: [subscription], subscriptionIDsToDelete: nil)

operation.modifySubscriptionsCompletionBlock = { saved, deleted, error in
  if let error = error{
    print("Add subscription error: \(error)")
  }else{
    print("Successfully added Question subscription.")
  }
}

//:::
let container = CKContainer(identifier: "...")
container.publicCloudDatabase.add(operation)
```